# Infer 3D location (Height, Latitude, Longitude) based on Signal Strength

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, signal-processing, antennas

Sorry if my question is irrelevant.

Let's consider two cases:

$1)$ Suppose that we have an Antenna and a tagged individual that can be pinged from the Antenna. Suppose that the individual is pinged repeated times within a time interval. For each time we record the signal strength. For this case does there exist a function of the following form

$$SignalStrength = f(Height, Latitude, Longitude)$$

i.e. to be possible to infer the $3$D location based on how the signal strength changes?

$2)$ Now suppose that we have $3$ Antennas. I've seen that there are methods that given that the individual was detected from all the Antennas we can create something like a triangular area in which the individual must be inside there. In this case, can we create something similar?

$$SignalStrength = f(Height, Latitude, Longitude)$$

---

Overall, I would like to learn about a way that based on the Signal Strength of one or more than one Antennas can infer the location of the individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a [dipole antenna in free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_field_strength_in_free_space) transmitting the signal strength (power density) is $p(r)= k/r^2$ where $r$ is the distance. Note that it only depends on distance, so knowing $p(r)$ will only tell you $r$ if you know $k$ (the emission power). So with just one sensor you will only know how far away the antenna is: it can be anywhere on a sphere of radius $r$ from the sensor.

If you have two sensors at $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2$ you can tell the tagged person is somewhere on the circle defined by $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_1||=r_1, ||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_2||=r_2$ but not anything more. Add a third sensor, and now you will have only two possible points that are at 3 given distances from the sensors. With a fourth sensor the problem is overconstrained, and now there is only one solution.

(If you send out a ping and it is reflected, then the signal strength decreases as $k/r^4$, but the situation is the same. If there are objects damping or reflecting signals things turn *much* more complicated.)

In practice radio signals can give much more information. If you sweep a directional antenna you get angle information by observing in which direction the signal is strongest. Dipole antennas have a directionality of their $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ vectors that can also give some extra information. Still, you likely need at least several points to pinpoint where the person is, solving for the most likely location. See [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20090126163503/http://www.interlinknetworks.com/graphics/news/wireless_detection_and_tracking.pdf) for how it can be done in practice when looking for rogue Wi-Fi cards.

Comment: Really enlightening, thank you for that! When I google emission power it gives me, as a result, Effective radiated power, I assume they refer to the same thing. Now, let's specify the type of antenna, the Yagi–Uda antenna. For which we have a measured Signal Strength for a person, and I also assume that the emission power is fixed for each antenna?? So, we could potentially calculate the distance between the antenna and the persion as $r = \sqrt{k/p(r)}$??

Comment: I think the Yagi-Uda antenna design makes it rather directional, so now the simple analysis above needs to take angle information into account.

Comment: Yes, they say that the Yagi-Uda antenna has a 35 angle coverage of the area that it is pointed to. So, we just have to take also into account into the formula above